# How Can I migrate magento 1.9 code to magento 2.3

Tags: magento, magento2, newsletter, billing

I created a newsletter checkbox on magento 1,9 checkout and it work fine. There is the code :

**app/design/frontend/default theme/default/template/persistent/ Checkout/onepage/billing.phtml**

```
Newsletter : <input type="checkbox" name="billing[is_subscribed]" title="" value="1" id="billing:is_subscribed" class="checkbox" checked="checked" />
```

And finaly : **app/code/core/(le nom de ton Magento)/Checkout/controllers/Onepagecontroller.php**

```
  if (isset($data['is_subscribed'])) {
        $status = Mage::getModel('newsletter/subscriber')->subscribe($data['email']);
    }
```

It work like charm in magento 1.9 **but I do not know how to put that in Magento 2.3 is not the same structure :/**

Someone can help me ?
Best regards

Comment: Hi, Did you read this article? https://www.cloudways.com/blog/migrate-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

Comment: Thank you for your response but I need only to find the equivalent of saveBillingAction() function and checkout form "billing.phtml"  in Magento 2.3. It's complicate to do this migration ? The code must be change too ?

Comment: It's not going to be as easy as that in M2, you can check this out: https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/

Comment: I understand :( It looks more complicated than version 1.9 :(